# How to read .sql file which contains multiple lines using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an issue while reading .sql file from s3 bucket using Pyspark and my .sql file contains one sql with multiple lines its very big sql can't put it in a single line.

snippet of code.

```py
query = sc.textFile(query_path).collect()
df_test = spark.sql(query)
```

getting below error:

```py
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o88.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ? I am also trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're reading the query file through spark, but you can perhaps try this, which joins the whole text file into 1 line.

```
query = ' '.join(sc.textFile(query_path).collect())
df_test = spark.sql(query)
```